# Errors with json_decode, array and foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I use this code for Virtuemart:

```
$product_id_to_remove = 3;
$cart = json_decode($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']);
foreach($cart->cartProductsData as $k => $v){
  if($v->virtuemart_product_id == $product_id_to_remove) unset($cart->cartProductsData[$k]);
}
$_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart'] = json_encode($cart);
```

but I get the fatal error: **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in** ... line 4. If I add true at json_decode($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']) I get the warning: **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**.

How to resolve the problem?

p.s. I'm beginner in php and don't know json_ at all. The code is suggested by the link: [stackoverflow.com/questions/28691203/how-to-remove-a-single-product-from-mod-virtuemart-cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691203/how-to-remove-a-single-product-from-mod-virtuemart-cart)

Comment: If you use `true` for the 2nd parameter, you need to refer to `$cart['cartProductsData']` as it returns an associative array rather than class.

Comment: Try `foreach(get_object_vars($cart->cartProductsData) as $k => $v)`

Comment: Warning: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in

Comment: which line is line 5?

Comment: Sorry, I meant line 4: if($v->virtuemart_product_id == ...

Comment: Do `var_dump($cart);` to see if there is key like 'cartProductsData'

Comment: `object(stdClass)#454 (27) { ["cartProductsData"]=> object(stdClass)#447 (2) { ["1"]=> object(stdClass)#458 (3) ...`

Comment: sorry but I don't know Virtuemart, i just want to know the value of this: `print_r($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart'])`

Comment: `{"cartProductsData":{"1":{"virtuemart_product_id":3 ...`

Comment: I think your array gets confused. Can you do `print_r($cart);`? I find that easier to read than `var_dump()`

Comment: `stdClass Object ( [cartProductsData] => stdClass Object ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_product_id] => 3 [quantity] => 1 [customProductData] => Array ( ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_product_id] => 2 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$cart->cartProductsData` behaves like an array but it's actually an object

try this:
change

```
unset($cart->cartProductsData[$k])
```

to

```
unset($cart->cartProductsData->$k)
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is one problem: if I replace [$k] to ->$k, the product is being removed but after a while isn't, so I replace back ->$k to [$k] and removing works again but after a while I get stdClass' error, then I replace [$k] to ->$k again and the circle closes

Comment: This is probably due to having one or more products in cart. Add a check to see if it is just one object or an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know php so well. Can you write conditions for each case?

Comment: Research a little, you want to learn, right? Otherwise I will have to send you an invoice, so I can do the work for you. Search for is_object/is_array.